# What happens to Harvey Dent when the car turns over in The Dark Knight?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

I was watching The Dark Knight after a long time and I noticed one scene where Two Face goes after the people who helped Joker kidnap him and Rachel Dawes. So he is sitting in a car with the gangster. They have talk and Two Face flips the coin. The clean side comes which means the guy is saved, but when he flips the coin for second time, destroyed face comes up. So Two Face says that the driver isn't lucky and shoots him.

The exterior shot shows the car flipping in air and crashing. How did Two Face escape the accident? Also, even if someone manages to escape such an accident, he would be badly injured. In case of an already-injured man, this situation should have escalated very badly.

Comment: Harvey was willing to play Russian Roulette against Batman and Gordon. The possibility of dying in the car crash seems like a calculated risk he was willing to take.

Answer (score 9):

Immediately after Two Face flips the coin for the second time and implies he's going to kill the driver, he puts on his seatbelt.

The seatbelt is implying that he fully intends to cause a car crash by killing the driver, killing Maroni in the process. If you have a look at the video, Maroni isn't wearing a seatbelt, Two Face putting on the seat belt implies thats all he needs to do to survive the car crash, horrific or not.

Comment: One day, they will show this in schools to promote seatbelt use.  "He may have only had a half a face, but he had a whole brain, and it told him to use that seatbelt conveniently located next to his shoulder."

Comment: @Praxis That's the same day they start using Gatorade to water crops.

Comment: Essentially, Dent survives!

Answer (score 1):

This is fully explained in the [film's script](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uwV8rddtKRgC&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=%22Dent%20flips%20the%20coin%20again.%20Looks%20down%20at%22&source=bl&ots=0xiA5ew31B&sig=OLXka0MjHxEoAvda2X2SbwB6fk8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=npaVVZCgA-W17gadpqOIAw&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Dent%20flips%20the%20coin%20again.%20Looks%20down%20at%22&f=false);

> **DENT:** *I said it couldn’t hurt your chances.*
>
> [Dent flips it. Looks: good side. He shrugs.]
>
> *Lucky guy.*
>
> [Maroni looks confused. Dent flips the coin again. Looks down at the
>   coin. Shakes his head]
>
> **DENT:** *But he’s not.*
>
> **MARONI:** *Who?*
>
> [Dent smiles. **Puts his seat belt on.**]
>
> **DENT:** *Your driver.*
>
> Dent presses the barrel of the revolver behind the shadow of the
>   driver. Maroni lunges, screaming. Dent fires.

And the film's [official novelisation](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(Book));

> Dent flipped the coin again: bad side. “But he’s not.”
>   “Who?” Maroni asked, confused.
>   The limo made its way out of the train yard.
>   **Dent fastened his seat belt and shot the driver.**
>   The limo sped forward and crashed into an abandoned shack, then flipped over, crashed beyond repair.

In short, his seatbelt was 100% effective in saving his life.